# byte level de-duplication implementation

Tags: duplicates

I want to develop the byte level de-duplication that is removing the redundant bytes and replace it with pointers to unique bytes , 
if I removed the duplicated byte and replace it with address memory to another memory location that has unique byte , then I did not reduce the storage space but I replace byte of data with reference to other byte ?!
I want idea for efficient way to remove duplicated bytes and reducing the size of data

Comment: Problem is that the pointer takes more than a byte :)

Comment: yes exactly ! and what is the solution can you suggest some idea plz ?

Comment: what is the problem? you want to compress the RAM? that's impossible because you need the RAM for the decompression

Comment: no I want to compress the files using the byte level de-duplication to reduce its size and save more storage space ! and at same time I must be able to restore the files to its original size any time